# Converting raster to TIN in ArcMap 10.1 is causing crashes?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, lidar, raster-conversion, tin, esri-ascii-raster

I have several tiles (~200) of Lidar 1m resolution data from Geomatics group and need to convert it to TIN format (currently in .asc) to develop a flood model.

1. Is there a quicker way of doing this than doing each individually?
2. I have reached a point where now I go to convert a file, Arc crashes and does not even produce an error report.

Currently using tiles in the format of .asc. Converting them using the 3D analyst tool - from raster - raster to TIN. Using the max number of points as the set 1500000 and z factor 1. Have reached a point where when I am trying to convert tiles, the system crashes without being able to generate a report. Also, very slow in showing the TIN drawn data.